# overflow hidden adding in body tag which remove the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

i don't know why but due to some ad code or any other reasons, overflow hidden is adding in main body which remove the scroll bar from the page.

```
<body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden">
```

How i can prevent this or how we overwrite the overflow:hidden to overflow:auto

Comment: you should track that tag by inspector of firefox or chrome, or use body{overflow:auto !important;} in your css

Comment: Should i know the reason for why you use overflow:hidden in body tag..?? Because you did't give any fixed height to it...Any scenarios..?

Comment: i am not using overflow:hidden, some third party party control adding this in body, so i remove by add overflow: visible !important; in css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite this using `!important`;

in your css file:

```
body {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS:

```
body {
    overflow:auto !important;
}
```

This should always overwrite the inline element.